# MS Graph User Data Access from AAD using Java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access MS Graph for an AAD account using Java. It is to fetch all User Data. When trying to access MS Graph I get 401 error:

```
            ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                            Collections.singleton("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"))
                    .build();

            CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);

            URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + future.get());
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

            int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(httpResponseCode == HTTPResponse.SC_OK) {

                try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        responseString.append(inputLine);
                    }
                }
            }
          return responseString.toString();
```

Scope and other permissions are given.
I am getting following result. Hope anyone can guide me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Where is your code for implenting Notification when new user is added in AAD?

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT I am thinking of first implementing https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users , by fetching access token to make sure I am following the right way. This is the code for fetching user data from AAD. Now I am able to fetch the token successfully, but not user data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my latest code. I used the function `getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant` to fetch access token and called the GET api call manually by adding access token to the header. Using graph client is the best practice as of my knowdeldge.

```
            String CLIENT_ID = "{{ClientId}}";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "{{ClientSecret}}";
            String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantId}}";
            Set<String> SCOPE = Collections.singleton("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        try {

            String access_token = getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
                    AUTHORITY, SCOPE).accessToken();

            URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

            int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            JsonPointer responseString = null;
            if(httpResponseCode == HTTPResponse.SC_OK) {

                try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                       response.put(RESULT, responseString.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Response "+responseString);
```

And getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant function goes like this :

```
 private IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant(String client_id, String client_secret, String authority, Set<String> scope) throws MalformedURLException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication
            .builder(client_id, ClientCredentialFactory
                    .createFromSecret(client_secret))
            .authority(authority).build();

    ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters
            .builder(scope).build();

    CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
    return future.get();
}
```

Suggested readings :
https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2021/08/microsoft-graph-why-you-cannot-call-the-me-endpoint-with-a-token-acquired-via-the-client-credentials-grant-flow/

Comment: It can be really helpful if you also add a few words to describe your answer, rather then just posting the code